error This project's package.json defines "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4". However the current global version of Yarn is 1.22.22
error This project's package.json defines "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4". However the current global version of Yarn is 1.22.22.
cmd open paste = npm pkg set packageManager="yarn@1.22.22"

You will need to activate corepack.
Run this command:
corepack enable

And this:
yarn install

If you don't have corepack installed, check this out: Corepack | Yarn

Remove this line from your package.json.
"packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4"


The project should obviously be running on yarn 3.6.4 since it was included in the package.json. Removing it is only fixing the error for one person while changing the project setup for everybody else.

You should update ReactNative to 0.74.

Yarn 3 for New Projects
Upgrade guide - Step by step


My solution was to add to my package.json
"packageManager": "yarn@1.22.22"

With that I forced my project to use 1.22.22
